# How can I filter a view by date ranges from another content type?

Tags: 7, views

I am building a site in Drupal 7 that has a list of events.  I would like to be able to filter these events by specific date ranges from another content type.

I have successfully been able to set up a view that enables users to filter the list of events by a number of criteria including an arbitrary date range. That much is fine.

However, I would like to allow users to filter the events into date ranges that come from another content type.  In this particular case I want the site to show events that occur within the term of office of UK prime ministers.  I have set up a content type that has the start and end dates of the term of office of the prime ministers but I can't see how to use this to filter the events.

Ideally I would like a drop down list that allows the user to select a prime minister and this will show a list of events that occur during that prime minister's term of office.

How would you suggest that I do this?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I think you will have to write a custom Views 3 filter handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a dropdown list, but if you don't want to write code, consider the following.

Create a view of all UK PM's in a view. Rewrite the results to output links in the format: events/*start_date*/*end_date*.

On your events view (with 'events' path). Add contextual filters catching start_date and end_date.

You could make the first view a jump menu and show it as a block above your events view. This will have the same effect as exposed filters, but will be harder to combine with actual exposed filters.

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful.  I have managed to get this working. In case it helps anyone else I output the links in the format: _events/in/YYYY-MM-DD--YYYY-MM-DD_ rather than using a slash between the start and end dates.